# Create MAPI profile using c++

Tags: c++, include, outlook, mapi

I am trying to create an outlook profile and I found [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306962)

And i am trying to us the: "Use the MAPI IProfAdmin interface" but I dont know what "include" I need to us.

if you know a better way to create outlook profile without user interaction it will help :)

Comment: You also might want to refer MAPI Bible "Inside MAPI".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc815345.aspx) for this interface, You need to include `<Mapix.h>`.

Comment: thx it helped but it cant identify "PR_PROFILE_UNRESULVED_SERVER" i tried searching and i think i need "edk.h" but i dont have it on my computer, can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Download [MFCMAPI](http://mfcmapi.codeplex.com/) source code - besides showing how to use just about every MAPI object, it includes all the up-to-date header files